# If anonymous JavaScript functions can access all variables, what about regular functions?

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function

In Javascript function variables are local unless they're not declared with "var". That is, unless those functions are anonymous (like the ones used in setInterval and setTimeout. In that case, they have global access to all available variables within the scope that called the anonymous functions.

What about regular functions then? Is there any way to allow them to access all variables too? I ask this due to some cases of having very complicated functions under 1 parent function with many variables, where I suddenly have to turn them from anonymous into regular functions.

For example, let's assume my original anonymous function called alert and now I want to do it through a regular function:

```
myFunction()
function myFunction() {
    var a='b' //,b=...,c=...,d=...,e=...,f=...,g=...,h=...,i=...,j=...,k=...
    setInterval(function(){ alert(a) }, 3000) // Works even though a is local
    setInterval(function(){ dummy() }, 3000) // Fails, but would work if I used dummy(a).
    // But then I'd have to use dummy(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,...)
}

function dummy() { // It would have worked had I used dummy(a)
    alert(a)
}
```

Comment: There's no essential difference other than the lack of a name between anonymous functions and named functions.

Comment: Well, there is at least one major difference. Like I've shown above, anonymous functions can access local variables as if they were global, whereas named functions can't. That's the purpose of this question.

Comment: Your assertion is wrong.  What matters is *where* the function is defined, not whether it has a name or not.

Comment: Move the declaration of `dummy()` inside `myFunction()` and it'll have access to `a`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is *not* about anonymous functions. Take this two lines:

```
 setInterval(function named (){ alert(a) }, 3000);
 setInterval(function(){ alert(a) }, 3000);
```

both work although one is named, and one is not. The real problem here is scoping, `a` is not visible to `dummy` because `dummy` gets declared outside of `a`'s scope:

```
  { // brackets start a scope
    let a = "b"; // a gets declared in this scope
    //...
  } // scope ends

  function dummy() { /*..*/ } // outside of scope
```

To solve this, move `dummy` into `a`'s scope:

```
 function myFunction() { // start of scope
   let a = "b"; 
   setInterval(function(){ dummy() }, 3000);

   function dummy() { 
    alert(a); // a can be accessed as it is inside of the scope
   }
 } // end of scope
```

*(I used `let` instead of `var` because it has stricter, and therefore easier to justify, scoping rules)*

Comment: `var` doesn't care about brackets. It's scope is the function where it is used. the second block of code in the answer suggests that a variable declared with `var` inside a `for` loop is not visible outside the `for` block.

Comment: @axiac indeed, but I didnt want to confuse the OP with block / function scoping